# Mathematical optimization and operation research

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I was formulating a mathematical model for vessel optimization.While formulating constraints,there was a constraint which stated that a single container can handle a single type of oil. So i was not able to formulate this constraint in mathematical form.Please help me out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not dedicate one variable (or a set of variables if needed) for each oil type?